# what does this piece of javascript do and can i remove it safely?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, head

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    var Translator = new Translate({"HTML tags are not allowed":"HTML-code is niet toegestaan","Please select an option.":"Selecteer a.u.b. een optie.","This is a required field.":"Dit is een verplicht veld.","Please enter a valid number in this field.":"Voer a.u.b. een geldig getal in dit veld in.","The value is not within the specified range.":"De waarde is niet beschikbaar.","Please use numbers only in this field. Please avoid spaces or other characters such as dots or commas.":"Gebruik a.u.b. alleen getallen in dit veld, vermijd spaties of andere tekens zoals punten en komma's","Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field.":"Gebruik uitsluitend letters  (a-z en A-Z) in dit veld.","Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.":"Gebruik uitsluitend letters (a-z en A-Z) in dit veld. Gebruik geen spaties of andere tekens. Het eerste teken moet een letter zijn.","Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z) or numbers (0-9) only in this field. No spaces or other characters are allowed.":"Gebruik uitsluitend letters (a-z en A-Z) in dit veld. Gebruik geen spaties of andere tekens.","Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z) or numbers (0-9) or spaces and # only in this field.":"Gebruik uitsluitend letters (a-z en A-Z) in dit veld. Gebruik geen spaties of andere tekens.","Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.":"Geef a.u.b. een geldig telefoonnummer op. Bijvoorbeeld (123) 456-7889 of 123-456-7890","Please enter a valid fax number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.":"Geef a.u.b. een geldig faxnummer op. Bijvoorbeeld (123) 456-7889 of 123-456-7890","Please enter a valid date.":"Geef a.u.b. een geldige datum op.","The From Date value should be less than or equal to the To Date value.":"De Datum vanaf\" moet eerder zijn dan de \"Datum tot\".\"","Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.":"Geef a.u.b. een geldig e-mailadres op. Bijvoorbeeld: iemand@domein.nl.","Please use only visible characters and spaces.":"Gebruik uitsluitend letters (a-z en A-Z) in dit veld. Gebruik geen spaties of andere tekens.","Please enter 6 or more characters. Leading or trailing spaces will be ignored.":"Voer a.u.b. zes of meer tekens in. Spaties aan begin of eind zullen worden genegeerd.","Please enter 7 or more characters. Password should contain both numeric and alphabetic characters.":"Voer a.u.b. zes of meer tekens in . Wachtwoorden moeten zowel numerieke en alfanumerieke tekens bevatten.","Please make sure your passwords match.":"Zorg dat de wachtwoorden overeenkomen.","Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http:\/\/, https:\/\/ or ftp:\/\/)":"Geef een geldige URL op. Protocol is vereist (http:\/\/, https:\/\/ or ftp:\/\/)","Please enter a valid URL. For example http:\/\/www.example.com or www.example.com":"Voer a.u.b. een geldige URL in. Bijvoorbeeld http:\/\/www.voorbeeld.com of www.voorbeeld.com.","Please enter a valid XML-identifier. For example something_1, block5, id-4.":"Voer a.u.b. een geldige XML-identifier in. Bijvoorbeeld something_1, block5, id-4.","Please enter a valid social security number. For example 123-45-6789.":"Geef a.u.b. een geldig Burger Service Nummer op. Bijvoorbeeld 123-45-6789.","Please enter a valid zip code. For example 90602 or 90602-1234.":"Voer een geldige postcode in a.u.b. Bijvoorbeeld: 2900 of 6621BK","Please enter a valid zip code.":"Geef een geldige postcode op.","Please use this date format: dd\/mm\/yyyy. For example 17\/03\/2006 for the 17th of March, 2006.":"Gebruik dd\/mm\/jjjj als datum-formaat. Bijvoorbeeld 17\/03\/2006 voor 17 maart 2006.","Please enter a valid $ amount. For example $100.00.":"Voer een geldig \u20ac bedrag op. Bijvoorbeeld: \u20ac100,00.","Please select one of the above options.":"Selecteer a.u.b. \u00e9\u00e9n van de hierboven genoemde opties.","Please select one of the options.":"Selecteer a.u.b. \u00e9\u00e9n van de opties.","Please select State\/Province.":"Selecteer a.u.b. een provincie.","Please enter a number greater than 0 in this field.":"Voer in dit veld a.u.b. een getal groter dan 0 in.","Please enter a number 0 or greater in this field.":"Voer in dit veld a.u.b. een getal gelijk aan of groter dan 0 in.","Please enter a valid credit card number.":"Geef a.u.b. een geldig creditcard-nummer op.","Credit card number does not match credit card type.":"Kaartnummer niet geldig voor deze creditcard-maatschappij.","Card type does not match credit card number.":"Kaartnummer niet herkend door creditcard-maatschappij\/","Incorrect credit card expiration date.":"Onjuiste vervaldatum van creditcard.","Please enter a valid credit card verification number.":"Geef a.u.b. een geldig creditcard-nummer op.","Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.":"Gebruik uitsluitend letters (a-z en A-Z), cijfers (0-9) of underscores (_) in dit veld, eerste letter moet een een letter zijn.","Please input a valid CSS-length. For example 100px or 77pt or 20em or .5ex or 50%.":"Voer een geldige CSS-lengte in. Bijvoorbeeld 100px, 77pt of 50%.","Text length does not satisfy specified text range.":"Tekstlengte komt niet overeen met de gespecificeerde lengte.","Please enter a number lower than 100.":"Voer in dit veld a.u.b. een getal lager dan 100 in.","Please select a file":"Selecteer een bestand","Please enter issue number or start date for switch\/solo card type.":"Voer een geldig nummer of een geldige startdatum in voor het switch\/solo kaarttype.","Please wait, loading...":"Bezig met laden... Een ogenblikje a.u.b.","This date is a required value.":"Datum is een verplicht veld.","Please enter a valid day (1-%d).":"Geef a.u.b. een geldige dag op (1-%d).","Please enter a valid month (1-12).":"Geef a.u.b. een geldige maand op (1-12).","Please enter a valid year (1900-%d).":"Geef a.u.b. een geldig jaar op (1900-%d).","Please enter a valid full date":"Geef a.u.b. een geldige volledige datum op.","Please enter a valid date between %s and %s":"Geef a.u.b. een geldige datum op tussen %s en %s.","Please enter a valid date equal to or greater than %s":"Geef a.u.b. een geldige datum op groter of gelijk aan %s","Please enter a valid date less than or equal to %s":"Geef a.u.b. een geldige datum op gelijk aan of kleiner dan %s","Complete":"Voltooid","Add Products":"Producten toevoegen","Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest":"Kies a.u.b. met met of zonder account wilt afrekenen.","Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no shipping methods available for it. Please make necessary changes in your shipping address.":"Uw bestelling kan niet worden afgerond omdat er geen verzendmethodes voor beschikbaar zijn. Breng de nodige wijzingen aan in uw afleveradres a.u.b.","Please specify payment method.":"Specificeer a.u.b. de betaalmethode.","Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no payment methods available for it.":"Uw bestelling kan niet worden afgerond omdat er geen betaalmethodes voor beschikbaar zijn.","Add to Cart":"In winkelwagen","In Stock":"Op voorraad","Out of Stock":"Niet op voorraad"});
    //]]></script>
```

This piece of javascript is visible in source code of page, in head area.

What does it do and can it be removed safely (how?)? I have checked multiple Magento sites and not all of them have this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article explain your question.

Basically, Translator is a Magento object which is using for translate in Javascript. For example: if you write your own module which will do some ajax request, and you want to translate content here (label, placeholder, etc). However, you don't want to mess js and php code like `title="<?php echo $this->__('Title')?>"`, you can do in other way like that with jQuery: `selector.attr('title', Translator.translate('Tile'))`. That is one case where you can use translator object. In my opinion, one advantage of this approach is that will makes code separated, clean and more maintainable.

I don't remove this file, to prevent something broken but we can overwrite it by overwrite `jtranslator.xml` in your theme. More information how to do it in these link.

[How to override core template files from a custom module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62134/how-to-override-core-template-files-from-a-custom-module)

[How to Copy Code/Core system.xml file into Code/local in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9852/how-to-copy-code-core-system-xml-file-into-code-local-in-magento)

Source: http://bartosz-gorski.com/magento/magento-1-7-and-1-8-javascript-translations-translate-js/

Hope it can help your a bit. cheer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's function is to provide the localization (Translation from 1 language to another) for one, or more, Javascript functions.

You could remove it, but any Javascript functions calling the `Translator` variable would cause an error.

Comment: AFAIK missing texts in the Translator do not cause an error, just the texts won't be translated anymore.

Comment: I was thinking more of any JS function calling the Translator variable directly (i.e. I'd assume an error of "Translator does not exist" to be hit)

Comment: You're totally right, removing the line entirely will result in errors