# Magento:Template File

Tags: magento-1.9, template, custom, file

I want to add a custom button in checkout page through my module without affecting any core functionalities of checkout module.

http://i.prntscr.com/b2500547a0a747e5883be2a84fa43545.png

Comment: what you have tried so far ??

Comment: Igot the answer.I have used the following link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62134/how-to-override-core-template-files-from-a-custom-module. It was just a mistake in the reference name.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify below file and put in your theme for that

Copy

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

Paste and modify

```
/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the following to your config.xml under the `<config>` tag:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
    <updates>
        <modulename>
            <file>package_modulename.xml</file>
        </modulename>
    </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then you need to create your layout file **app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/package_modulename.xml** with the following content:

```
<?xml version="0.1.0">
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <checkout_cart_index>
     <reference name="checkout.cart">
          <block type="core/template" name="extra_block" template="link/to/your/template/cart.phtml" />
     </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>

</layout>
```

Then in your `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/checkout/cart.phtml` you'll need to add the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_block'); ?>
```